# Removing specific key-value pairs from a document/object

Tags: javascript, dictionary, underscore.js

I have a document that looks like something like this:

```
{
  name: "Johnny Boy",
  age: 24,
  hobbies: ["fencing", "chess", "raves"],
  _createdAt: 2015-05-15T18:12:26.731Z,
  _createdBy: "JohnnyBoy",
  _id: mQW4G5yEfZtsB6pcN
}
```

**My goal is to return everything that doesn't start with an underscore**, and format it a bit differently so I will end up with this:

```
[
  {
    fieldName: "name",
    value: "Johnny Boy"
  },
  {
    fieldName: "age",
    value: 24
  },
  {
    fieldName: "hobbies",
    value: ["fencing", "chess", "raves"]
  }
]
```

My initial solution was to run it through the `_.map` function of the Underscore library (which has nothing to do with my wanting to remove underscores specifically...) and then using `lastIndexOf` to figure out which keys begin with an underscore:

```
var listWithoutUnderscores = _.map(myList, function(val, key) {
  if (key.lastIndexOf("_", 0) === -1)
    return {fieldName: key, value: val}
  return null
})
```

However, this will literally return `null` instead of the fields that began with `_` in the returned array:

```
[
  ...
  {
    fieldname: "hobbies",
    value: ["fencing", "chess", "raves"]
  },
  null,
  null,
  null
]
```

I want to **remove them completely**, ideally within the `map` function itself, or else by chaining it through some kind of filter but I don't know which one is fastest in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [reduce](http://underscorejs.org/#reduce) for this:

```
var listWithoutUnderscores = _.reduce(myList, function(list, val, key) {
  if (key.lastIndexOf("_", 0) === -1){
    list.push( {fieldName: key, value: val});
  }
  return list;
}, []);
```

Comment: A rather complicated function but it does the job well. What's the `[]` for at the end?

Comment: It's the initial value for the `list` parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Underscore also comes with an array method `compact` which will remove all falsey and null values from an array:

```
_.compact([0, 1, false, 2, '', null, 3]);
=> [1, 2, 3]
```

You could just call `_.compact(array)` on the array after your map.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[pick](http://underscorejs.org/#pick)** and pass a predicate to get the valid keys and then [**map**](http://underscorejs.org/#map) across those fields:

```
var validKey = function(value, key){
    return _.first(key) != '_';
}

var createField = function(value, key){
    return {
        fieldname: key,
        value: value
    }
}

var result = _.chain(data)
    .pick(validKey)
    .map(createField)
    .value();
```

```js
var data = {
  name: "Johnny Boy",
  age: 24,
  hobbies: ["fencing", "chess", "raves"],
  _createdAt: '2015-05-15T18:12:26.731Z',
  _createdBy: "JohnnyBoy",
  _id: 'mQW4G5yEfZtsB6pcN'
}

var validKey = function(value, key){
  return _.first(key) != '_';
}

var createField = function(value, key){
  return {
    fieldname: key,
    value: value
  }
}

var result = _.chain(data)
   .pick(validKey)
   .map(createField)
   .value();

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This returns an empty array for me, and without the `value()` an underscore.

Comment: Oops - had the parameters to createField the wrong way round. Also added a snippet showing it working.

Comment: Yeah, I actually noticed that error. The faulty result came from running this inside Meteor, which apparently doesn't include `_.chain`. Using a workaround library fixed it. I do like the neatness of this code but I don't know how fast it is compared to the other suggestions.